# Is there an explicit factorization rule for mixed moments under free independence?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, functional-analysis, probability-theory, solution-verification

Let $\varphi$ be a unital linear functional on a unital algebra $A$,
and let $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ be a family of unital subalgebras of $A$.

The family $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ is said to be *tensor independent* if

1. the subalgebras commute, i.e.,
   $a_ia_j = a_ja_i$ for all $a_i\in A_i$ and $a_j\in A_j$ and all $i,j\in I$, $i\neq j$,
   and
2. mixed moments factorize, i.e.,
   \begin{equation*}
   \varphi\bigg(\prod^n_{k=1}a_k\bigg) = \prod^n_{k=1}\varphi(a_k)
   \end{equation*}
   for any positive integer $n$
   and any elements $i_k$ in $I$ and $a_k$ in $A_{i_k}$, $k=1,\ldots,n$,
   where the $i_1,\ldots,i_n$ are distinct.

I believe I can show that an equivalent definition is obtained when
the second condition regarding factorization of mixed moments
is replaced by the condition that centered mixed moments vanish, i.e.,
\begin{equation*}
\varphi\bigg(\prod^n_{k=1}a_k^o\bigg) = 0
\end{equation*}
where $a^o = a - \varphi(a)1$ is the *centering* of $a$ for any $a$ in $A$.
This then means that the condition of vanishing centered mixed moments
implies the factorization of mixed moments.

The condition of vanishing centered mixed moments is also the one used in
the definition of free independence:
the family $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ is said to be *freely independent* if
\begin{equation*}
\varphi\bigg(\prod^n_{k=1}a_k^o\bigg) = 0
\end{equation*}
for any positive integer $n$,
elements $i_1,\ldots,i_n$ in $I$
and $a_1\in A_{i_1},\ldots, a_n\in A_{i_n}$,
such that $i_1\neq i_2,\ldots,i_{n-1}\neq i_n$,
i.e., neighbouring $a_i$ come from different subalgebras.

**Question:**
Similar to the case of tensor independence,
in the case of free independence
is there an explicit formula for the factorization of mixed moments?

**Edit:**
I have answered my own question,
but I am not sure whether the solution I have derived is correct.
Any feedback would be appreciated!

**Initial intuitive approach (but see my own answer below for more details):**
For an explicit formula I have the following intuition.
Let $n$ be a positive integer,
let $[n] = \{1,\ldots,n\}$,
let $j$ be a mapping from $[n]$ into the index set $I$,
and let $a_k\in A_{i_k}$ for $k=1,\ldots,n$.
Let $\text{Ker}(j)$ be the
[equivalence kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation)
of $j$, i.e.,
the set of inverse images of elements in the image $j([n])$ of $j$:
\begin{equation*}
\text{Ker}(j) = \{j^{-1}(\{y\}):y\in j([n])\}.
\end{equation*}
The set $\text{Ker}(j)$ is a partition of $[n]$.
I am not sure,
but my intuition tells me that maybe if $\text{Ker}(j)$ is
[noncrossing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set#Noncrossing_partitions)
then
\begin{equation*}
\varphi\bigg(\prod^n_{k=1}a_k\bigg)
=
\prod_{V\in\text{Ker}(j)}
\varphi\bigg(\prod_{k\in V}a_k\bigg)
.
\end{equation*}
The reason I believe that this may be true is because for any $m=1,\ldots,n$,
and as by definition $a_m = a_m^o + \varphi(a_m)1$,
it holds that
\begin{equation*}
\varphi\bigg(\prod^n_{k=1}a_k\bigg)
=
\varphi\bigg(
\bigg(\prod^{m-1}_{k=1}a_k\bigg)
a_m^o
\bigg(\prod^n_{k=m+1}a_k\bigg)
\bigg)
+
\varphi(a_m)
\varphi\bigg(
\bigg(\prod^{m-1}_{k=1}a_k\bigg)
\bigg(\prod^n_{k=m+1}a_k\bigg)
\bigg).
\end{equation*}
In the second term the mixed moment is of a length one less than the original one,
and the first term contains one less element that is not centered.
Iteration of this rule will then (maybe) converge to a sum of terms that either
contain no mixed moments
or which have centered mixed moments
(where neighbouring elements come from different subalgebras).
The latter vanish because of free independence of the subalgebras
where the $a_k$ come from.
If $\text{Ker}(j)$ is noncrossing
then in the application of the above rule I think (maybe)
there is always a block $V$ in $\text{Ker}(j)$
such that the $a_k$ with $k\in V$ are neighbouring
which can be isolated in the application of the above rule,
and iteration then (maybe) results in the factorization rule given above.
I admit this is a bit vague and I am not sure whether my intuition is right.

If $\text{Ker}(j)$ is crossing,
then the above factorization formula in general does not hold true.
For example,
if $a_1,a_2\in A_1$ and $b_1,b_2\in A_2$ then
\begin{equation*}
\varphi(a_1b_1a_2b_2)
=
\varphi(a_1a_2)\varphi(b_1)\varphi(b_2)
+
\varphi(a_1)\varphi(a_2)\varphi(b_1b_2)
-
\varphi(a_1)\varphi(b_1)\varphi(a_2)\varphi(b_2).
\end{equation*}
See e.g. Lectures on the Combinatorics of Free Probability by Nica and Speicher, page 71.
But in that case,
is there still an explicit formula that can be given?

**Edit:**
It seems a similar question has been posted on Math Overflow,
but with no answer yet:
[Recursive formula for joint moments in free probability](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/114805/recursive-formula-for-joint-moments-in-free-probability).

**Side note:**
A weaker result is known to hold true:
for any subalgebras $A_{i_1},\ldots,A_{i_n}$
the restriction $\varphi|_B$ of $\varphi$
to the algebra $B$ generated by $A_{i_1},\ldots,A_{i_n}$
is determined by the free independence relation and the restrictions
$\varphi_{A_{i_1}},\ldots,\varphi_{A_{i_n}}$.
See e.g. page 69-70 in Lectures on the Combinatorics of Free Probability
by Nica and Speicher.

Answer (score 1):

For the case where $\text{Ker}(j)$ is noncrossing
and the general case I have now come to
the following proof.

**Case of noncrossing $\text{Ker}(j)$:**

Suppose that $\text{Ker}(j)$ is noncrossing.
Then there is a block $V$ in $\text{Ker}(j)$ that is an interval, i.e.,
there are $r$ and $s$ in $[n]$ such that
$V = [r,s] = \{k\in\mathbb{N}:r\leq k\leq s\}$
and
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\prod_{k\in[n]}a_k
&=
\bigg(\prod_{k\in[1,r-1]}a_k\bigg)
\bigg(
\bigg(\prod_{k\in V}a_k\bigg)^o
+
\varphi\bigg(\prod_{k\in V}a_k\bigg)
1
\bigg)
\bigg(\prod_{k\in[s+1,n]}a_k\bigg)
\\
&=
\bigg(\prod_{k\in[1,r-1]}a_k\bigg)
\bigg(\prod_{k\in V}a_k\bigg)^o
\bigg(\prod_{k\in[s+1,n]}a_k\bigg)
+
\varphi\bigg(\prod_{k\in V}a_k\bigg)
\bigg(\prod_{k\in[n]\setminus V}a_k\bigg)
.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Note that the element
$\big(\prod_{k\in V}a_k\big)^o$
lies in the subalgebra $A_v$,
where $v\in I$ such that $j(V) = \{v\}$,
and the elements
$a_1,\ldots,a_{r-1},a_{s+1},\ldots,a_n$
all do not lie in $A_v$.
The partitions
$\text{Ker}(j|_{[1,r-1]})$,
$\text{Ker}(j|_{[s+1,n]})$
and
$\text{Ker}(j|_{[n]\setminus V})$
of respectively
$[1,r-1]$,
$[s+1,n]$
and
$[n]\setminus V$
are all noncrossing,
hence the above decomposition can in turn be applied to the terms
$\prod_{k\in[1,r-1]}a_k$,
$\prod_{k\in[s+1,n]}a_k$
and
$\prod_{k\in[n]\setminus V}a_k$.
Iterating in this way we eventually obtain a sum of terms,
where one term equals
\begin{equation*}
\prod_{V\in\text{Ker}(j)}
\varphi\bigg(\prod_{k\in V}a_k\bigg)
\end{equation*}
and each of the other terms is a scalar multiple of
a product of centered elements
such that neighbouring elements come from different subalgebras.
Due to the free independence of the subalgebras $(A_i)_{i\in I}$
those other terms vanish.

**General case:**

The general case appears to be a case of
[Möbius inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula)
of free cumulants.

For each positive integer $n$,
let $NC(n)$ be the lattice of noncrossing partitions of $[n] = \{1,\ldots,n\}$,
and for each $\pi$ in $NC(n)$ and $a_1,\ldots,a_n\in A$ let
\begin{equation*}
\kappa_{\pi}(a_1,\ldots,a_n)
=
\sum_{\substack{\sigma\in NC(n)\\ \sigma\leq\pi}}
\varphi_{\sigma}(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\mu_n(\sigma,\pi),
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\kappa_{n}(a_1,\ldots,a_n)
=
\sum_{\sigma\in NC(n)}
\varphi_{\sigma}(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\mu_n(\sigma,1_n),
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
\varphi_{\sigma}(a_1,\ldots,a_n)
=
\prod_{V\in\sigma}
\varphi\bigg(
\prod_{i\in V}a_i
\bigg),
\end{equation*}
$\mu_n$ is the Möbius function on $NC(n)$,
and $1_n = \{[n]\}$ is the top element in $NC(n)$.
The $\kappa_{\pi}$ are the free cumulants on $(A,\varphi)$.

The mixed moment $\varphi(a_1\cdots a_n)$ equals
$\varphi_{\sigma}(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$
in the case where $\sigma$ is the top element in $NC(n)$,
i.e., the partition $\{[n]\}$ with just one block $[n]$,
hence we can apply Möbius inversion to obtain
\begin{equation*}
\varphi(a_1\cdots a_n)
=
\sum_{\substack{\pi\in NC(n)\\ \pi\leq\{[n]\}}}
\kappa_{\pi}(a_1,\ldots,a_n)
=
\sum_{\pi\in NC(n)}
\kappa_{\pi}(a_1,\ldots,a_n)
.
\end{equation*}
One can show that

1. the cumulants $\kappa_\pi$ are multiplicative, i.e.,
   they factorize over the blocks $V$ in $\pi$ according to
   \begin{equation*}
   \kappa_\pi(a_1,\ldots,a_n)
   =
   \prod_{V\in\pi}
   \kappa_{m}(a_{i_1},\ldots,a_{i_m}),
   \end{equation*}
   where $\{i_1,\ldots,i_m\} = V$
   and $m = |V|$ is the block size of $V$
   (see e.g. Nica & Speicher, p.175-176),
   and
2. cumulants $\kappa_m(a_{i_1},\ldots,a_{i_m})$ vanish
   when the $a_{i_1},\ldots,a_{i_m}$ do not all lie
   in the same subalgebra of $A$
   (see e.g. Nica & Speicher, p.183).

Thus only those cumulants $\kappa_\pi(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ contribute
for which each $V\in\pi$ satisfies $V\subseteq W$
for some $W\in\text{Ker}(j)$,
i.e., $\pi\leq\text{Ker}(j)$.

The partition $\text{Ker}(j)$ may be crossing.
Let us first look at the case where it is not crossing,
to get some intuition on how to proceed in general.
In the case of noncrossing $\text{Ker}(j)$
the sum over $\pi\in\text{NC}(n)$
reduces to one over $\pi\in\text{NC}(n)$, $\pi\leq\text{Ker}(j)$.
Using the defining equation of free cumulants,
and letting $\zeta_n$ be
the [zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_algebra#Special_elements)
of $\text{NC}(n)$,
i.e., the constant function with value $1$,
and $\delta_n$ the unit element in the incidence algebra of $\text{NC}(n)$,
and using that the convolution of $\mu_n$ with $\zeta_n$ equals $\delta_n$,
we obtain
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\varphi(a_1,\ldots,a_n)
&=
\sum_{\substack{
\pi\in\text{NC}(n)
\\
\pi\leq\text{Ker}(j)
}}
\kappa_{\pi}(a_1,\ldots,a_n)
\\
&=
\sum_{\substack{
\pi\in\text{NC}(n)
\\
\pi\leq\text{Ker}(j)
}}
\sum_{\substack{
\sigma\in\text{NC}(n)
\\
\sigma\leq\pi
}}
\mu_n(\sigma,\pi)
\prod_{V\in\sigma}
\varphi\bigg(
\prod_{k\in V}a_k
\bigg)
\\
&=
\sum_{\substack{
\sigma\in\text{NC}(n)
\\
\sigma\leq\text{Ker}(j)
}}
\sum_{\substack{
\pi\in\text{NC}(n)
\\
\sigma\leq\pi\leq\text{Ker}(j)
}}
\mu_n(\sigma,\pi)
\zeta_n(\pi,\text{Ker}(j))
\prod_{V\in\sigma}
\varphi\bigg(
\prod_{k\in V}a_k
\bigg)
\\
&=
\sum_{\substack{
\sigma\in\text{NC}(n)
\\
\sigma\leq\text{Ker}(j)
}}
\delta_n(\sigma,\text{Ker}(j))
\prod_{V\in\sigma}
\varphi\bigg(
\prod_{k\in V}a_k
\bigg)
\\
&=
\prod_{V\in\text{Ker}(j)}
\varphi\bigg(
\prod_{k\in V}a_k
\bigg)
.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

If $\text{Ker}(j)$ is crossing,
then the above approach does not directly apply
because $\text{Ker}(j)$ does not lie in $\text{NC}(n)$
and there is no convolution over intervals
$[\sigma,\text{Ker}(j)]$ in $\text{NC}(n)$.
It would be nice though if we can still apply the above approach
with some modifications.
I now make an attempt at this.

Either way,
whether $\text{Ker}(j)$ is crossing or not,
any $\pi\in\text{NC}(n)$ satisfies $\pi\leq\text{Ker}(j)$
if and only if $\pi\leq\tau$ for some maximal element $\tau$ of
$\{\rho\in\text{NC}(n):\rho\leq\text{Ker}(j)\}$.
Let
\begin{equation*}
M = \max(\{\rho\in\text{NC}(n):\rho\leq\text{Ker}(j)\}).
\end{equation*}
The summation over $\pi\in\text{NC}(n)$
bounded from above by $\text{Ker}(j)$
can thus be replaced by summations over $\pi\in\text{NC}(n)$
bounded from above by one or more elements $\tau$ in $M$,
i.e.,
bounded from above by $\bigwedge S$ for some nonempty subset $S$ of $M$,
but proper compensation should be made
for $\pi\in\text{NC}(n)$ that are bounded from above by more than one
$\tau$ in $M$.
We are going to count those subsets $S$.
For any $\pi\in\text{NC}(n)$, $\pi\leq\text{Ker}(j)$,
if $P = \{\tau\in M:\pi\leq\tau\}$
then for each $k=1,\ldots,|P|$
there are $\binom{|P|}{k}$ subsets $S$ of $P$
with cardinality $|S| = k$,
and by the binomial theorem
\begin{equation*}
\sum^{|P|}_{k=1}
\binom{|P|}{k}
(-1)^{k-1}
=
1
+
\sum^{|P|}_{k=0}
\binom{|P|}{k}
(-1)^{k-1}
=
1
-
\sum^{|P|}_{k=0}
\binom{|P|}{k}
1^{|P|-k}
(-1)^{k}
=
1
.
\end{equation*}
Thus by multiplying with $(-1)^{|S|}$
each sum over $\pi\in\text{NC}(n)$, $\pi\leq\bigwedge S$,
and adding over all nonempty subsets $S$ of $M$,
each $\pi\in\text{NC}(n)$, $\pi\leq\text{Ker}(j)$,
will be considered precisely once:
\begin{equation*}
\varphi(a_1\cdots a_n)
=
\sum_{\varnothing\neq S\subseteq M}
(-1)^{|S|-1}
\sum_{\substack{
\pi\in\text{NC}(n)
\\
\pi\leq\bigwedge S
}}
\kappa_{\pi}(a_1,\ldots,a_n)
.
\end{equation*}
Using the defining equation of free cumulants,
the fact that the zeta function $\zeta_n$ by definition
is constant with value $1$,
and that the convolution of $\mu_n$ with $\zeta_n$ equals $\delta_n$,
i.e., the unit element,
we obtain for each nonempty subset $S$ of $M$ that
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{\substack{
\pi\in\text{NC}(n)
\\
\pi\leq\bigwedge S
}}
\kappa_{\pi}(a_1,\ldots,a_n)
&=
\sum_{\substack{
\pi\in\text{NC}(n)
\\
\pi\leq\bigwedge S
}}
\sum_{\substack{
\sigma\in\text{NC}(n)
\\
\sigma\leq\pi
}}
\mu_n(\sigma,\pi)
\prod_{V\in\sigma}
\varphi\bigg(
\prod_{k\in V}a_k
\bigg)
\\
&=
\sum_{\substack{
\sigma\in\text{NC}(n)
\\
\sigma\leq\bigwedge S
}}
\sum_{\substack{
\pi\in\text{NC}(n)
\\
\sigma\leq\pi\leq\bigwedge S
}}
\mu_n(\sigma,\pi)
\zeta_n(\pi,\bigwedge S)
\prod_{V\in\sigma}
\varphi\bigg(
\prod_{k\in V}a_k
\bigg)
\\
&=
\sum_{\substack{
\sigma\in\text{NC}(n)
\\
\sigma\leq\bigwedge S
}}
\delta_n(\sigma,\bigwedge S)
\prod_{V\in\sigma}
\varphi\bigg(
\prod_{k\in V}a_k
\bigg)
\\
&=
\prod_{V\in\bigwedge S}
\varphi\bigg(
\prod_{k\in V}a_k
\bigg)
.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
So for the general case of factorization of mixed moments we find
\begin{equation*}
\varphi(a_1\cdots a_n)
=
\sum_{\varnothing\neq S\subseteq M}
(-1)^{|S|-1}
\prod_{V\in\bigwedge S}
\varphi\bigg(
\prod_{k\in V}a_k
\bigg)
.
\end{equation*}